# Windows Azure iOS Push Notifications Error

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

Am trying to use Windows Azure for push notifications to iOS, Android etc.

On iOS I have the following code that create and register with Windows Azure.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *) deviceToken {

    NSString * connectionString =
    [SBConnectionString stringWithEndpoint: [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://AA-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"] listenAccessSecret:@"BBBBB"];

    SBNotificationHub*hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString: connectionString notificationHubPath:@"AA"];


    [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError* error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Register successful");
        }
    }];
}
```

When I run on my device I get the error below that am not sure what is causing this:

> Error registering for notifications: Error
>   Domain=WindowsAzureMessaging Code=-1 "Initiate request failed for
>    { URL:
>   https://AA-ns.servicebus.windows.net/BB/Registrations/2131816658076175975-431628186293699175-5?api-version=2013-04,
>   headers: {
>       Authorization = "SharedAccessSignature sr=http%3a%2f%AA-ns.servicebus.windows.net%AA%2fregistrations%2f2131816658076175975-431628186293699175-5%3fapi-version%3d2013-04&sig=yW6mDy6RbpgWHi9NINUv2zZ4cbaI6tcC91nGlg%2FjT%2B4%3D&se=1413280889&skn=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature";
>       "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
>       "User-Agent" = "NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2013-04(api-origin=IosSdk; os=iPhone OS; os_version=8.0.2;)"; } }" UserInfo=0x16014600
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Initiate request failed for
>    { URL:
>   https://AA-ns.servicebus.windows.net/BB/Registrations/2131816658076175975-431628186293699175-5?api-version=2013-04,
>   headers: {
>       Authorization = "SharedAccessSignature sr=http%3a%2f%AA-ns.servicebus.windows.net%AA%2fregistrations%2f2131816658076175975-431628186293699175-5%3fapi-version%3d2013-04&sig=yW6mDy6RbpgWHi9NINUv2zZ4cbaI6tcC91nGlg%2FjT%2B4%3D&se=1413280889&skn=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature";
>       "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
>       "User-Agent" = "NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2013-04(api-origin=IosSdk; os=iPhone OS; os_version=8.0.2;)"; } }}

(I removed reference to my application name)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: If you are using mobile services as well, can you try using [client.push registerNativeWithDeviceToken: tags: completion:] and seeing if that works?  That would help narrow down the issue to the params/client side vs your notification hub.

Comment: have you solved your issue!? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest WindowsAzureMessaging.Framework (available here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/p/?LinkID=266533) and then try changing your code to this:

```
SBNotificationHub *hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:
                @"NotificationHubListenSharedAccessSignature"
                notificationHubPath:@"NotificationHubName"];
```

Replace the two parameters with values for your Hub.  Make sure the HubName is specifically just the name of your Notification Hub and not your Service Bus namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error as indicated above.